# What is a normal healthy amount of Titratable acid in a person's blood?

Tags: hematology

A person's normal pH for arterial blood is 7.41 and venous blood is 7.36. 
But I am curious to what is a normal amount of Titratable Acid in someone's blood?

Comment: As you say yourself blood is kept in a slightly basic range (and this is tightly controlled). Why do you think there should be free acid present here?

Comment: There are proton pumps involved with pH regulation, right?

Comment: @GabrielFair yes, what's your point? Just because there is a proton pump doesn't mean there's free hydronium ion (or any other type of acid ion) in circulation. In fact, *in vivo* it's exactly the opposite.

Comment: Isn't titratable acidity expressed as percent lactic acid? Isn't there lactic acid in the blood?